# Matlab : image region analyzer. Alternative for 'bwpropfilt'?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm running basic edge detection to detect windows region based on this *http://www.mathworks.com/videos/edge-detection-with-matlab-119353.html*

The `edge` works successfully :

```
final_edge = edge(gray_I,'sobel');
BW_out = bwareaopen(imfill(final_edge,'holes'),20);
figure; 
imshow(BW_out);
```

Now when come to these following codes to filter image based on properties, it seems like my ***MATLAB R2013a*** can't identify this `bwpropfilt` method.

```
% imageRegionAnalyzer(BW);

% Filter image based on image properties
BW_out = bwpropfilt(BW_out,'Area', [400, 467]);
BW_out = bwpropfilt(BW_out,'Solidity',[0.5, 1]);
```

It says:

*`Undefined function 'bwpropfilt' for input arguments of type 'char'.`*

Then what should be my alternative to change this `bwpropfilt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bwpropfilt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwpropfilt.html) simply takes a look at the corresponding attribute that is output from `regionprops` and gives you objects that conform to that certain range and also filtering out those that are outside of the range.  You can rewrite the algorithm by explicitly calling [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html), creating a `logical` array to index into the structure to retain only the values within the right range (seen in the third input of `bwpropfilt`) corresponding to the property you want to examine (seen in the second input of `bwpropfilt`).  If you want to finally reconstruct the image after filtering, you'll need to use the column major linear indices found in the `PixelIdxList` attribute, stack them all into a single vector and write to a new output image by setting all of these values to `true`.

Specifically, you can use the following code to reproduce the last two lines of code you have shown:

```
% Run regionprops and get all properties
s = regionprops(BW_out, 'all');

%%% For the first line of code
values = [s.Area];
s = s(values > 400 & values < 467);

%%% For the second line of code
values = [s.Solidity];
s = s(values > 0.5 & values < 1);

% Stack column major indices
ind = vertcat(s.PixelIdxList);

% Create output image
final_out = false(size(BW_out));
final_out(ind) = true;
```

`final_out` contains the filtered image only retaining the values within the range specified by the desired property.

## Caution

The above logic only works for attributes returned from `regionprops` that contain only a single scalar value per unique region.  If you examine the supported properties found in `bwpropfilt`, you will see that this list is a subset of the full list found in `regionprops`.  This makes sense as certain `regionprops` properties return a vector or a matrix depending on what you choose so using a range to filter out properties becomes ambiguous if you have multiple values that characterize a particular unique region returned by `regionprops`.

## Minor Note

Being curious, I opened up `bwpropfilt` to see how it is implemented as I currently have MATLAB R2016a.  The above logic, with the exception of some exception handling, is essentially how `bwpropfilt` has been implemented so the code that I wrote is in line with the logic of the function.

Comment: My God I've been just wandering around your profile, you're a living Einstein! Btw, thank you very much!

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup hahaha you're too kind :) I wouldn't call myself an Einstein per se mainly because I think I have better arithmetic skills :D.  Either way, thank you very much for the sentiments and you are very welcome.  Good luck!